# How to generate Camera Videos in Nuplan

Tags: python

Recently, I am interested in examining user reactions to various autonomous vehicle scenarios, and I've identified the nuPlan and NuScenes datasets as potentially valuable resources for my work.

While I've been able to follow the NuScenes tutorial and easily visualize the 20-second camera video using the code **nusc_explorer.render_scene(scene_token)**, I've encountered some challenges with the nuPlan tutorial.

In the NuScenes dataset, the images names (e.g., n008-2018-08-01-15-16-36-0400__CAM_FRONT__1533151603512404.jpg) are self-explanatory, enabling me to merge them as videos directly. However, when working with nuPlan and following the tutorial (https://github.com/motional/nuplan-devkit/blob/master/tutorials/nuplan_sensor_data_tutorial.ipynb), I find that I can only visualize a single image. Moreover, the image names (e.g., 0a133a28509e550a.jpg)in CAM_F0 don't clearly indicate their content or context.

Does anyone know the appropriate procedure to better understand and generating camera video of scenarios in NuPlan?

Thanks so much!

appropriate procedure to better understand and generating camera video of scenarios in NuPlan